# PHP not able to read JSON but writes extra lines in SQL

Tags: javascript, php, sql, json

I have an HMTL form with 3 fields on it, Firstname, Lastname and image upload file. When submit is pressed it calls the following JS script.

```
//main function to be called on submit
function processData() {

  var firstName = document.querySelector('#first-name'),
    lastName = document.querySelector('#last-name'),
    imageUser = document.querySelector('#image-user');

  var formSubmitData = {

    'firstName': firstName.value,
    'lastName': lastName.value,
    'imageUser': imageUser.value
  };

  var dataString = JSON.stringify(formSubmitData);

  if (navigator.onLine) {
    sendDataToServer(dataString);
  } else {
    saveDataLocally(dataString);
  }

  firstName.value = '';
  lastName.value = '';
  imageUser.value = '';
}

//called on submit if device is online from processData()
function sendDataToServer(dataString) {

  var myRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
  //new code added so data is sent to server

  //displays popup message - data sent to server 
  myRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {

    if (myRequest.readyState == 4 && myRequest.status == 200) {

      console.log('Sent to server: ' + dataString + '');
      window.localStorage.removeItem(dataString);
    } else if (myRequest.readyState == 4 && myRequest.status != 200) {

      console.log('Server request could not be completed');
      saveDataLocally(dataString);
    }
  }

  myRequest.open("POST", "write_test.php", true);
  //Send the proper header information along with the request
  myRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  myRequest.send(dataString);

  alert('Sent: ' + dataString + ''); //remove this line as only for example
}
```

As you will see it sends a POST request to the php page. The "datastring" is encoded as JSON.

I use the following PHP code to send the data to the SQL server, but all it does is create a blank record with no data but it does create a new record.

```
<?php
 //TRYING NEW CODE TO EXTRACT DATA FROM dataString
 $json = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true);
 $data = json_decode($json, true);
 echo '<pre>' . print_r($data, true) . '</pre>';
 // INSERT into your contact table.
 $sql="INSERT INTO contacts (firstName, lastName)VALUES('$firstName','$lastName')";
```

How do I get it to create records in SQL with data that has been submitted from the form??

Comment: Why are you decoding the result twice?

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)***. Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

Comment: Are you executing the query? What result do you get from `print_r()`? It is a safe bet you're not getting the variables `$firstName` and `$lastName`, so we'd need to see the JSON to tell you how to get those.

Comment: I take it the first line should be the only decode line? $json should read $data?

Comment: Yes, you only need to decode once. The variables, based on that, should be in the `$json` array, likely `$json['firstName]` and `$json['secondName']`

Comment: The JSON  is  {"firstName":"FIRSTNAME","lastName":"LASTNAME","imageUser":""}

Comment: So if you use the first line where you decode the data will be in the variables stated in my comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63454541/php-not-able-to-read-json-but-wrutes-extra-lines-in-sql#comment112206618_63454541) not `$lastName` or `$firstName`

Comment: You can't use `.value` to get the value of a file input. You need to post a `FormData`, and then you can use `$_POST` and `$_FILES` to get the posted data.

Answer (score 0):

I have no final solution as I don't have the form code. Hope you are ready to learn.
I'm worried about user image - don't send any image for testing, but a string (like path) or nothing, please.
js - change for double quotes:

```
var formSubmitData = {
    "firstName" : firstName.value,
    "lastName" : lastName.value,
    "imageUser" : imageUser.value
};
```

php - leave only this

```
<?php
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));      // test only version
print_r($data);                         // test only version

/* 
and close the rest as a comment - SQL is fine, don't worry

$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input",true)); // final ver
echo print_r($data, true);                  // final ver
...   
*/
```

If you receive the right output, delete the trial version and good luck.
If not - go back to `var formSubmitData` to the values on the right - they are so naked ... without any quotes

And of course, take care of security (injection) and order, set the required at the inputs - you don't need empty submits